# getting file error or bank when adding to sharepoint list attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-list, react, typescript

I am getting a data serialize I think that is causing an issue with POST request, its getting success but the pdf or any file when I try to view from the source it generates error or blank image.

How to unserialize the data what I am getting this below data
[image]

And This is the function

```
onFileChangeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          files: e.target.files[0].name
        });
    };

<input type="file" name="Upload" onChange={this.onFileChangeHandler.bind(this)}/>
```

With this Input component. Also here I am adding this file with API call to the source Where I have to deserialize

```
  private createItem(): void {
// On Submit form, this function get trigger, to save the items into respected Sharepoint List selected from property pane
const listName = this.state.listValueText && this.state.listValueText ? this.state.listValueText : 'FormReactive';
const currentSiteUrl = this.state.endpointURL ? this.state.endpointURL : `https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Test-AppDev`;
const endpoint: string = currentSiteUrl + `/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('` + listName + `')/items`;
this.setState({
  status: 'Creating item...',
  items: [],
});

const body: string = JSON.stringify({
  'Title': this.state.subject,
  'Comments': this.state.comments
});

this.props.spHttpClient.post(endpoint,
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
  {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
      'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
      'odata-version': ''
    },
    body: body
  })

  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> => {
    console.log(response,'RESp');

    return response.json();
  })
  .then((item: IListItem): void => {
    if (this.state.UploadedFilesArray !== undefined) {
      try {
        sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.add({
        }).then(r => {
          // this will add an attachment to the item we just created to push t sharepoint list
          r.item.attachmentFiles.add(this.state.UploadedFilesArray.name, this.state.UploadedFilesArray).then(result=>{
          });
        })
      } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      status: `Item '${item.Title}' (ID: ${item.Id}) successfully created`,
      items: []
    });
  }, (error: any): void => {
    this.setState({
      status: 'Error while creating the item: ' + error,
      items: []
    });
  });
```

}

I think because of serialize data my attachment file is showing failed or blank. I searched internet and thought that deserialize will solve this.
Can anyone help me with this? deserializing the above data.

Answer (score 0):

Test demo.

```
export interface IReactDropdownState {
  selectedItem?: { key: string | number | undefined };
  options: any[];
  modalIsOpen: boolean,
  pdfFile: File
}

public constructor(props: ITestSpFxProps, state: IReactDropdownState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [],
      modalIsOpen: false,
      pdfFile: null
    };

<input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.files)} />
<button onClick={(e) => this.Submit()}>Submit</button>

handleChange(selectorFiles: FileList) {
    this.setState({ pdfFile: selectorFiles[0] });
  }

  Submit() {
    console.log(this);
    if (this.state.pdfFile !== undefined) {
      try {
        sp.web.lists.getByTitle("TestList").items.add({
          Title: "New Item"
        }).then(r => {
          // this will add an attachment to the item we just created to push t sharepoint list
          r.item.attachmentFiles.add(this.state.pdfFile.name, this.state.pdfFile).then(result=>{
            console.log(result);
          });
        })
      } catch{

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey, Its working but now it is creating 2 new entries in sharepoint list. I;ve updated the question with latest code function, can you check where I am doing mistake.